# Custom hooks not working properly with useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I wasn't sure on a title for this issue, but I can better explain it here. I have a custom hook that is relying on some information. Part of the information must rely on an async call.

I have three situations happening.

1. Tried conditionally rendering the custom hook, but react does not like that due to rendering more hooks on a different render.
2. The custom hook is only mounting once and not passing in the updated information it needs.
3. I tried passing the dependency to the custom hook and it causes an infinite loop.

Here is a small example of what I'm doing.

Custom Hook:

```js
export function useProducts(options){ 
  const [products, setProducts] = useContext(MyContext)

  useEffect(() => {
    // only gets called once with `options.asyncValue` === null
    // needs to be recalled once the new value is passed in
    const loadProducts = async () => {
      const data = await asyncProductReq(options)
      setProducts(data)
    }
    loadProducts()
  }, []) // if I pass options here it causes the infinite loop

  return [products, setProducts]
}
```

Inside function calling:

```js
export function(props){
 const [asyncValue, setValue] = useState(null)

 useEffect(() => {
   const loadValue = async () => { 
     const data = await asyncFunc()
     setValue(data)
   }
   loadValue()
 }, []}

 const options = {...staticValues, asyncValue}
 const [products] = useProducts(options)
 return (
  <h2>Hello</h2>
 )
}
```

I know that I need to pass the options to be a dependency, but I can't figure out why it's causing an infinite reload if the object isn't changing once the async call has been made inside the func.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were correct in adding `options` in the dependencies list for your custom hook.

The reason it is infinitely looping is because `options` IS constantly changing.

The problem is you need to take it one step further in the implementation and make use of the `useMemo` hook so options only changes when the async value changes, instead of the whole component changing.

So do this:

```
const options = React.useMemo(() => ({...staticValues, asyncValue}), [asyncValue])
```

Comment: Not sure why I didn't think of that! I think I'm just having some "jet" lag from using classes haha.

Comment: Totally cool dude! It took me a while to figure out that that was the issue :)